# why Generating random data using setInterval in react js not Generating after certain seconds?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, react-hooks, setinterval

i am trying to generate random data in react.but data start to move like after 1 seconds 1 entry then after another second 5 entries then 26 then 126 and so on mean after every second data is exponentially generate.But i want to generate only 1 record after 1 second

```
function App() {

const [pktD,setPktD]=useState({
    chid:0,
    peakVal:0,
})
const dataGen=setInterval( function(){
setPktD({...pktD,chid:Math.random()*253});
setPktD({...pktD,peakVal:Math.random()*10000})

},5000)
console.log(dataGen);
return (
<></>
);
}
```

I also try to implement in custom hook but facing same problem.First entry generate after 5 second but after that data generate random intervals.
myCustom hook is below i also tried this.

```
import React ,{useState} from "react"


function DataGenerator(){
const [pktD,setPktD]=useState({
    chid:0,
    peakVal:0
})
 const dataGen=function(){
setPktD({...pktD,chid:Math.random()*253});
setPktD({...pktD,peakVal:Math.random()*10000})
return pktD
}
 return [dataGen];
}
export default DataGenerator;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
  const [pktD, setPktD] = useState({
    chid: 0,
    peakVal: 0
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    const dataGen = setInterval(function () {
      // setPktD({ ...pktD, chid: Math.random() * 253 });
      // setPktD({ ...pktD, peakVal: Math.random() * 10000 });
      setPktD((prevState) => ({...prevState, chid: Math.random() * 253, peakVal: Math.random() * 10000}));
    }, 5000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(dataGen);
    }
  }, []);
  console.log(pktD);
  return <></>;
}

export default App;
```

Comment: kindly also explain my code problem and solution.

Comment: another thing.i dont want to generate data on useEffect.because it will run first time.Actually i want to make it like a real time data simulation which generate data after every second without reloading.

Comment: The problem with your code is that the setInterval updates the state which will trigger rerender which then creates a new interval. So, basically on every rerender the new setInterval will be created. The right way to do this would be to use `useEffect` which will register the setInterval once.

Answer (score 1):

because you are not clearning interval along  also use in useEffect beacuse its running async.